# confused: PPGA988, rPGA988B. what cpu socket is in my hp 4330s laptop and what cpus will it take?

Tags: laptop, cpu, processor-socket

Wow, I am so out of the loop these days with PC/laptop hardware. Upgrading a CPU is a whole lot more complicated than it was in the late 90s!

I have an HP 4330s laptop that according to CPU-Z, exactly matches [these specs on geekbench.](http://browser.primatelabs.com/geekbench3/274110)

[According to intel ark](http://ark.intel.com/products/53438/Intel-Core-i3-2350M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_30-GHz?q=2350m), the only supported socket for my i3-2350M CPU is "PPGA988".

Does that mean only [these cpus](http://ark.intel.com/search/advanced/?s=t&SocketsSupported=PPGA988) on intel ark will work?

I am confused because I have seen [forum posts](http://forum.notebookreview.com/hp-business-class-notebooks/640959-so-can-i-upgrade-cpu-4430s-probook.html) from people who have succesfully put and i7 in my laptop, which according to ark, is not supported. I have also heard that some sockets work with different pinouts of CPUs.

What socket have I got?
What CPUs can I take?

Thanks!

Comment: In either case, the type of socket your laptop uses, means you won't be able to replace because involves soldering the CPU to the motherboard.

Comment: I've seem people say that it is "socketed" in that model, which I presume means it isn't soldered. The forum post linked above said it is. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: I don't believe that PPBGA sockets are socketed they are soldered

Comment: @Ramhound this is PPGA, not BGA

Comment: That comment has a typo, but, my comment still applies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [service manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03054507.pdf) for your model on page 71 there is a list of CPUs this model shipped with and are verified to be working by HP. According to it, a [i7-2620M](http://ark.intel.com/pl/products/52231/Intel-Core-i7-2620M-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_40-GHz) is indeed supported. Other models may not be supported by the chipset or BIOS.

Comment: Thanks it worked fine in the end with an i7-2620M from ebay!

Answer (score 0):

Like kinokijuf mentioned always check the manual to see what is supported: just because the CPU fits physically doesn't mean the laptop will recognize it. The BIOS/UEFI is the limiting factor, often you must upgrade your BIOS/UEFI to a specific version before a newer and physically identical CPU is supported.

The reason the i7 works but you don't find it on the Intel site is that PPGA988 and FCPGA988 are almost identical. The number is the number of pins on the CPU. PGA means Pin Grid Array. This is often referred to as 'pin identical'.